# Can u-boot verify a signed hardware?

Tags: security, yocto, u-boot, imx6

i have found several pages and document describing how realize secure boot using i.MX6 processor and u-boot. This is fine for me, because it allow to be sure that only original FW (u-boot and kernel) can be load, but it is not sufficent. Actually i have also the necessity that only approved HW (aka signed in some extent) could be used for my FW. U-boot can verify the presence of a sort of signature on the processor (in particular i.MX6), for example the activation of HAB itself or the close state of ROM, and if so, how this functionality could be realized? THX!!

Comment: Did you try to ask on [NXP forum](https://community.nxp.com/)? BTW i saw a lot of patches coming for HAB in latest u-boot-imx.